# Html Element Not Aligning All The Way To The Left

Tags: html, css

I'm not new to HTML or CSS, but I really don't know why this is happening. I could just be dumb and this is an easy question something is really wrong. I'm really having trouble with this. I have a very simple web page with a div element. Not matter what I do I still have space at the top, side, and bottom of it. Here's a picture.

[image]

And Here's my HTML and CSS code.

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
      .SideBar {
        background: #4c4c4c;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 25px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
     <body style="background-color: #05bcff">
       <div class="SideBar">
          <p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
            asd
          </p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: From where do you want to remove the space... on the div element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign `margin` 0 and `padding` 0 to `body` element in your styling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. From the answers below I now have a clear understanding on why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `<body>` element has margin by default in some browsers. Different browsers can choose to apply some basic default styling to elements. Chrome, for example, adds 8px margin to  by default. If you set

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

This will dissappear.

A better way to go about it is to include [Reset.css](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) or [Normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) in your code. Reset.css will unstyle absolutely everything, so that what you write is exactly what is displayed. This gives you greatest control but for most cases it's too much. For example, `<h1> , <h2> , <h3>..` tags will all look the same after applying Reset.css .

Normalize.css on another hand preserves useful styling but will make sure that your elements are rendered consistently across all browsers. This is preferred in most cases.

In [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen) you can even try these out. If you click 'Settings' you can choose to include 'Normalize' or 'Reset' in your CSS. You can play around with these to see how your elements are displayed under each.

Comment: Thanks. I will try out Normalize.

Answer (score 1):

As Frontend employee said just add

```
.body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

a lot of people employee CSS reset codes at the top of their stylesheets which includes this. Its basically a list of default overrides that clears any styling on elements allowing you to begin with a clean slate
See (http://cssreset.com/scripts/html5-doctor-css-reset-stylesheet/)